# @JmsListeners for Generic Types?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a class that defines 2 JMSListeners. 1 listener is for a message `MyMessage1` that the client receives from a server that uses JMS. Another is for a `MyMessage2`, which is generated by another program, not using JMS (not a java program). It seems when I try to receive this message, I get some JMS Listener exceptions. It seems to be taking a GenericMessage and attempting to convert it to a `MyMessage`, despite the payload indicating it's a `MyMessage2`, although it doesn't specify the full java package name for it.

What exactly is a GenericMessage? Is this an indication that the sender is not properly identifying the message's type? Do I need to define a JMSListener for a generic message somehow and serialize it manually, rather than using the `JmsListenerContainerFactory`?

```
@JmsListener()
private void consumeMessage1(final MyMessge1 msg) { 
   //... 
}

@JmsListener()
private void consumeMessage2(final MyMessge2 msg) { 
   //... 
}


org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [private void my.proj.ResultQueueConsumer.consumeMessage1(my.proj.MyMessage1)]
Bean [my.proj.ResultQueueConsumer@24fe9d1]
; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found to convert to class my.proj.MyMessage1, message=GenericMessage [payload=MyMessage2{attr1='response', version='2.0', attr2='PROJ', attr3='ERROR'}, headers={JMS_AMQP_FirstAcquirer=false, jms_timestamp=0, hostId=my-machine1, requestId=c83b5719-daaa-43f8-9444-b16580d06950, jms_priority=4, jms_messageId=ID:my-machine1-41383-1486390497702-3:127:0:0:1, timestamp=1486391400112, id=33e78ff8-9e7b-1436-ee21-36cacb1ff6b5, JMS_AMQP_MESSAGE_FORMAT=0, jms_deliveryMode=1, jms_redelivered=false, JMS_AMQP_NATIVE=false, jms_destination=queue://Result, sessionId=057907c44eeb18e3940278973a610b2638d198c4, jms_expiration=0}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GenericMessage<>` is a `spring-messaging` object.

Incoming JMS messages are first converted to a `GenericMessage` and then the listener is invoked with components therefrom; for example, you could have a method signature

```
void foo(@Payload MyMessage2 msh, @Header("foo") int someHeader)
```

The error message indicates that a message with a `MyMessage2` has been received and the framework is trying to invoke your fist listener method.

If they are both listening to the same queue, the message will randomly go to one or the other listener, unless you add a `selector` and can somehow determine what the payload type is from a header (used in the selector expression).

The framework does not provide a mechanism to route to a particular method based on the payload type.

It's not clear what you mean by...

> Another is for a MyMessage2, which is generated by another program, not using JMS (not a java program).

... since we clearly were able to build a `MyMessage2` java object from the message.

Comment: Regarding my unclear message, I was suggesting that perhaps the message was not formed properly due to the program generating it not using java/jms ajnd perhaps leaving off some header info or somesuch, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I had no idea that it would randomly choose one of my JmsListeners if i had mulitple ones monitoring teh same queue. I'll need to either have the header have something unique to select off of, or perhaps use another queue.

Comment: Is it possible to have a single JmsListner for a generic message and then serialize them manually in to the known objects?

Comment: `void consume(Message<?> message)` then `message.getPayload()`.

Comment: OK. will the object returned by message.getPayload already be my java object, or do I need to do something else with it, like give it to a JAXB Context?

Comment: I can't tell from the log - `[payload=MyMessage2{attr1='response', version='2.0', attr2='PROJ', attr3='ERROR'}` - we just call `toString()` on the payload. Exactly what is being sent? If it's not a Java program, how is it talking to the JMS server?

Comment: XML is being sent and trying to serialize that back to a java object. It's an activemq server -- a C program is connecting to the queue using qpid proton. So you get the string of the payload object and then provide that to a JAXBContext to build the object?

Comment: Well, that payload is obviously not XML, so you must have configured some converter - why don't you just try it and look at the object in a debugger?

Comment: Ah, the payload was my toString() method I defined in the object. The message.getPayload returned my acutal object. simply had to do a type-check and casting. your JMS/Spring info helped immensely as usual. thanks.

Comment: Er, what I meant was that the log output was the result of calling toString() on my object as a result of the marshalling converter set up already.